# Outlook 2007/10/13 <style media="print"> work around

Tags: css, media-queries, html-email

I've encountered something that bugged me while testing my email marketing campaigns.

So here goes:

I use the following code so that images and some other bits won't print when a user prints the e-mail (It is for a hotel group so emails are printed often, with booking numbers and all).

```
<style media="print">
body { background-color:#FFFFFF; }
.no-print { display:none; }
</style>
```

Now, outlook 2007/10/13, aol mail and some other clients seem to consider themselves as printed media and apply the display:none rule on every no-print element, leaving the email in a dire state of emptiness.

I could remove it all completely, but that wouldn't be good practices for ecology.

Do any of you guys know of a work around?
Like a way to force outlook to consider itself as a screen media?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, I really don't think so. See this : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3232/how-do-i-create-a-printer-friendly-email-newsletter/

Comment: Yep there is no workaround for that, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have a better understanding of the question I think I found the beginning of a possible solution for you. This should ensure the printer style sheets CSS still work, but aren't displayed by clients, like Outlook 2007, when they shouldn't be.

- Ran test with email 'as is' and sure enough Outlook 2007 was blank because it applied the print style sheets
- Then I added this media query in the code example below
- Outlook 2007 shows up with the other clients so it's ignoring the print stylesheet
- Now in Google Chrome's print preview the text with `.no-print` doesn't display

Code Excerpt:

```
    <style media="print">

        @media only print {
            body { background-color:#FFFFFF; }
           .no-print { display:none; }
         }

    </style>

    </head>

<body >
<h1 class="no-print" style="font-size: 36px">LINE OF TEXT</h1>
```

Email Testing Link: https://litmus.com/pub/49bfd3b

Comment: That's not the actual problem, the problem is that outlook will render print styles at all times.

Comment: Sorry about that, you'll see I totally revised my answer and gave it another shot.

Comment: I'm not understanding how `media="print"` and `@media only print` work together in this case. Couldn't you simply have `media="only print"` without putting the styles in a `@media` rule instead?

Comment: @BoltClock, you're right -- I just assumed there was a reason it needed to be there. I'm assuming complexity when it could just be use media queries for print.

Comment: @RLacorne, do you need the style tags for any particular reason?